# C remove() function doesn't delete target file in windows environment

Tags: c, windows, file-pointer

I'm writing a program that asks the user for a file name, and creates it if it doesn't exist. At the end of the program, I want to check if the created program is empty, and if it is, delete it. Not deleting it and then running the program with that same file name messes up the way the input is detected.

I've tried using `rewind()` to go back to the beginning and then checking `feof()` to see if the beginning of the file was the EOF character, but that didn't work.

Then, I did some searching online, and found a method that used `fseek()` to go to the end of the file, and then checked with `ftell()` whether the end of the file was at position 0, but again this did not work.

I went back and did more poking around, and found that the problem might be because I hadn't used `fclose()` first, so I tried the previous two attempted solutions again, this time being sure to close the file before trying to delete it. Still no dice.

I tried checking what `errno` was set to, and got `2: No such file or directory`. This is patently false, since if that was the case, it would mean that I had accomplished my goal, and when I check the working directory, the file is still there.

I have absolutely no idea what to try next. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Here are the ways I've tried to delete the file (`fp` is the file pointer, and `file` is a char pointer with the name of the file that `fp` points to.) :

Attempt 1:

```
rewind(fp);
if(feof(fp)){
    remove(file);
}
```

Attempt 2:

```
fseek(fp, 1, SEEK_END);
long size = ftell(fp);
if(size == 0){
    remove(file);
}
```

Attempt 3:

```
fseek(fp, 1, SEEK_END);
long size = ftell(fp);
fclose(fp);
if(size == 0){
    remove(file);
}
```

Attempt 4:

```
rewind(fp);
int empty = 0;
if(feof(fp)){
    empty = 1;
}
fclose(fp);
if(empty == 1){
    remove(file);
}
```

UPDATE: Here's a couple MCVEs, one for each method.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>

int main() {
    FILE *fp;
    char file[40];
    scanf(" %[^\n]s", file);
    fp = fopen(file, "r");
    if(fp == NULL){
        fp = fopen(file, "w");
    int result;
    rewind(fp);
    int empty = 0;
    if(feof(fp)){
        empty = 1;
    }
    fclose(fp);
    if(empty == 1){
        result = remove(file);
    }
    printf("%d\n", result);
    printf("%d\n", errno);
    return 0;
}
```

Version 2:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>

int main() {
    FILE *fp;
    char file[40];
    scanf(" %[^\n]s", file);
    fp = fopen(file, "r");
    if(fp == NULL){
        fp = fopen(file, "w");
    int result;
    fseek(fp, 1, SEEK_END);
    long size = ftell(fp);
    fclose(fp);
    if(size == 0){
        result = remove(file);
    }
    printf("%d\n", result);
    printf("%d\n", errno);
    return 0;
}
```

UPDATE 2:

I just realized that when I was making the MCVEs, when I ran them, `result` was returning `0`, which *should* have meant that it was successful, but the file was still there in the directory. I'm at a loss for words.

Comment: when asking a question about a runtime problem, as this question is doing, post a [mcve] so we can recreate the problem and help you debug it.

Comment: Note: `feof()` is only true when the code has tried to read past the end of the file

Comment: note: fseek(fp, 1, SEEK_END);`  is trying to seek to 1 before the end of the file.  You should be checking the returned status.  So this statement should be: `int status = fseek(fp, 1, SEEK_END); if( status ) { perror( "fseek failed" ); }`

Comment: @user3629249 Okay, I'll put one together now and update the question

Comment: You did not mention which OS your using, however, in linux, and similar OSs, the `int stat(const char *pathname, struct stat *statbuf);` function returns in the 'statbuf` struct the information on how many bytes are in the file.  Please read the MAN page for `stat()` for further details
`

Comment: Also note on windows you may want to see [PathCanonicalizeA function | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/shlwapi/nf-shlwapi-pathcanonicalizea) and [File path formats on Windows systems](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/io/file-path-formats)

Comment: Sorry, I'm on Windows 7. Forgot to specify that.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin That first article seems to be specific to C++ at first glance, and the second one looks like it's for C#. I'll look through them anyway, though, thanks!

Comment: It is, the second has more of the meat and potatoes. For starters, what is your example input that causes the problem?

Comment: Try dumping the filename character by character to see if there's anything odd about it, like having a `\r` or something.

Comment: The title makes it sound like `remove` isn't working, but actually it seems your problem is that you are never calling `remove` (because you are failing at detecting that the file is empty). It would be better to confirm this (using a debugger or debug statements) and clean up your question so that it focuses on what the actual problem is

Comment: `scanf(" %[^\n]s", file);` Get RID of the `s`!!! The *character class*, e.g. `%[...]`, is a complete *conversion specifier* in and of itself.

Comment: @M.M That's it! I changed fseek(fp, 1, SEEK_END); to fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END); and now it works! Thank you!

Comment: That's not guaranteed to work for text files by the way,  a simpler method would be `rewind` followed by testing `fgetc(fp) == EOF`

Comment: When you solve a problem, post an answer. Do not update the title to say "Solved". The system doesn't use that to determine whether a problem has been solved. It uses the fact that an answer was posted and the answer was accepted. So do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code wasn't reaching the `remove` statement.